# Pagination in Large List of Data - Flutter / Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

i have data like this in dart, i want to show data according to offset and data limit, so i want to display that data in getData function which will be called inside main function

how can i display the data according to the offset and the limit that i pass through the parameter ?

```
import 'dart:convert';
 
void main() {
    
 var data = getData(5, 0);

  print(data.toString());
}


getData(int limit, int offset){ 
   List<Module> freeModuleList = [
     Module(
        id: '1',
        title: 'Mempelajari Data Part 5',
        publishedAt: DateTime.now(),
        progressUpdated: DateTime.now(),
         created: DateTime.now()),

  ];
  return freeModuleList;
}

class Module {
  final String id;
  final String title;
  final DateTime progressUpdated;
  final DateTime publishedAt;
  final DateTime created;

  Module({
    required this.id,
    required this.title,
    required this.created,
    required this.progressUpdated,
    required this.publishedAt,
  });
  
  @override
  String toString() => '''
    Module {
      id: $id,
      title: $title,
      created: $created,
      progressUpdated: $progressUpdated,
      publishedAt: $publishedAt,
    }
  ''';
}
```

Comment: Do you want to return the same Module data by the times of limits value?

Comment: @ShashankGb yes

Comment: what are you trying to do with offset ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the same data to be repeated by the times of `limit` value. You can do like this.

```
List<Module> getData(int limit, int offset) {
  Module eachModule = Module(
    id: '1',
    title: 'Mempelajari Data Part 5',
    publishedAt: DateTime.now(),
    progressUpdated: DateTime.now(),
    created: DateTime.now(),
  );
  List<Module> freeModuleList = [];
  for(int i = 0; i < limit; i++){
    freeModuleList.add(eachModule);
  }
  return freeModuleList;
}
```

I am not getting what are you doing with the offset and I am not seeing any widgets used in your question to adjust the offset.

This is answered, since you agreed in the comment section. I don't have an idea  how much it will be helpful